# Как сделать приветственное «модальное» окно?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cookie, localstorage

Как можно сделать приветственное окно, которое появляется, когда в первый раз заходишь на страницу?  А в низу сделать checkbox, чтобы в дальнейшем не показывать больше это окно.

```js
    var delay_popup = 1000;
    setTimeout("document.getElementById('overlay').style.display='block'", delay_popup);
```

```css
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  z-index: 999;
  -webkit-animation: fade .6s;
  -moz-animation: fade .6s;
  animation: fade .6s;
  overflow: auto;
}

.popup {
  top: 25%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;       
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 85%;
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #383838;
  background: #fefefe;
  z-index: 1000;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -ms-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font: 14px/18px 'Tahoma', Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.22),0 19px 60px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.22),0 19px 60px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.22),0 19px 60px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.22),0 19px 60px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  -webkit-animation: fade .6s;
  -moz-animation: fade .6s;
  animation: fade .6s;
}

.close {
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  border: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #0d47a1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;

}
.close:before {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  content: "X";
  font-family:  Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
/* кнопка закрытия при наведении */
.close:hover {
  background-color: #f44336;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay">
    <div class="popup">
        <h2>Модальное Окно!</h2>
        <p>Привет</p>
 
        <button class="close" title="Закрыть" onclick="document.getElementById('overlay').style.display='none';"></button>
        <input type="checkbox"> 
        <label>Больше не показывать</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: чекбокс тут явно излишний, показываете, вешаете куку. Я не мастер, но делается это примерно так: верстается блок, проверяется кука, если её нет, то показываем этот самый сверстанный блок, вешается кука (которая на "шаге 1" проверялась) по нажатию на кнопку (например крестик) или по таймауту блок скрывается. Лучше приведите код который вы уже написали, может так будет проще разобраться в вашей задаче.

Comment: @MedvedevDev добавил код, но на данный момент окно появляется каждый раз при загрузке страницы, а checkbox просто не работает (не знаю как сделать)

Comment: смотрите в сторону Cookie, чекбокс тут никак не поможет, если его состояние где-то не хранить (да и вообще чекбокс тут избыточен)

Comment: А вообще не делайте подобный функционал. Это не нужно, большинство людей содержимое таких окон не читает, а некоторых (меня) они вообще безумно раздражают.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Записывать можно в `cookie` или `localStorage`. Пример показывает запись в `localStorage`.

Пример в сниппете не работает из-за настроек безопасности. Поэтому вот пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3jfpbhbm/).

JS:

```
// Если стоит localStorage
if (!localStorage.getItem('isShowedHelloPopup')) {
  var delay_popup = 1000;
  setTimeout(() => document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'block', delay_popup);
}

function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'none';
  // Проверка, если стоит чекбокс
  if (showedHelloPopup.checked)
    localStorage.setItem('isShowedHelloPopup', 1);
}
```

CSS:

```
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  z-index: 999;
  -webkit-animation: fade .6s;
  -moz-animation: fade .6s;
  animation: fade .6s;
  overflow: auto;
}

.popup {
  top: 25%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 85%;
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #383838;
  background: #fefefe;
  z-index: 1000;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -ms-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font: 14px/18px 'Tahoma', Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .22), 0 19px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .22), 0 19px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .22), 0 19px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .22), 0 19px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  -webkit-animation: fade .6s;
  -moz-animation: fade .6s;
  animation: fade .6s;
}

.close {
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  border: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #0d47a1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

.close:before {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  content: "X";
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}


/* кнопка закрытия при наведении */

.close:hover {
  background-color: #f44336;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="overlay">
  <div class="popup">
    <h2>Модальное Окно!</h2>
    <p>Привет</p>

    <button class="close" title="Закрыть" onclick="closeModal()"></button>
    <label><input id="showedHelloPopup" type="checkbox"> Больше не показывать</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Блин, у меня эта функция тоже не работает

Comment: @user299170 Смотрите jsfiddle. Там все работает) А здесь в сниппете и не будет работать - это ограничение сниппета здесь.

Comment: я и не про  сниппет это у меня выдает ошибку фреймворке, сейчас пробую исправить